# Reading two (2-D) arrays from a file

Tags: c

I have a file with 3 (2-D) arrays that I need to fscan.

The problem is that when I fscan the first one only it's okay, but when I scan the second the first 3 elements of the first one change into spaces.

This how the first looks like:

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
0      1 X X X X X X X X  X
1      1 X X X X X X X X  X
2  1 1 1 X X X X X X X X  X
3  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
4  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
5  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
6  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
7  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
8  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
9  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
10 X X X X X X X X X X X  X
11 X X X X X X X X X X X  X
```

This is what happens after scanning the second array:

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
0        X X X X X X X X  X
1      1 X X X X X X X X  X
2  1 1 1 X X X X X X X X  X
3  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
4  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
5  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
6  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
7  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
8  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
9  X X X X X X X X X X X  X
10 X X X X X X X X X X X  X
11 X X X X X X X X X X X  X
```

And when I scan the third the first 3 elements of the second changed into spaces too.

NOTE: The first two elements are already spaces so you can see the change at this case happens to the third element in the first row of each array.

I tried to separate every array in a separated file and scan each one alone, but also the same problem o.O

```
void loadGrids(int rows, int columns, char grid[rows][columns],
               int numOfChoosedFile) {

  // getting the name of the file that we just got it's number
  char nameOfChoosedGameFile[FILENAME_MAX];
  snprintf(nameOfChoosedGameFile, FILENAME_MAX, "savedGrid%03d.txt",
           numOfChoosedFile);

  // opening the file that the game is saved in
  FILE *choosedGame = fopen(nameOfChoosedGameFile, "r");
  // reading data
  fseek(nameOfChoosedGameFile, 16, SEEK_SET);
  // this is to skip the first printed before the first array

  int j;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    j = 0;
    for (j; j < columns; j++) {
      fscanf(choosedGame, "%d", &grid[i][j]);
      printf("%c ", grid[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  close(choosedGame);
}
```

I have two other functions like this each to read every array.

Comment: thanks for answering 
the file has integer values
so reading them as char is giving me the numerical values as char
I need it to get the letter associated with the number in ASCI

Comment: So it might but using `%d` will write to 4 bytes (if `int` is 32-bit) of an array whose elements are only 1 byte. Did the compiler warn you about the mis-match of types?

Comment: Yes , but it runs
and the last scanned array has no problems
any pre scanned would get that

Comment: I tried now to print the data as char in files and read it as a char but also has a problem not the same but wrong data loaded

Comment: So you ignored the compiler warning "because it runs" even though the data is wrong?

Comment: If you must read `int` read it into a temporary `int` and then write that value into the array. `scanf` is brutal: if you tell it to write to 4 bytes, it will, although a modern compiler will try to warn you.

Comment: That absolutely WORKED :D
that was the fastest response ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must read `int` read it into a temporary `int` and then write that value into the array. `scanf` is brutal: if you tell it to write to 4 bytes, it will, although a modern compiler will try to warn you.
                    – Weather Vane

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
for (j; j < columns; j++) {
      **fscanf(choosedGame, "%d", &grid[i][j]);**
      printf("%c ", grid[i][j]);
    }
```

You're reading %d an int, but your grid is char * and when fscanf read your file is also a char *, so it will not read the whitespaces or when it reads, will convert the whitespace(a string) to int.

Change **%d to %c.**